Is there a way to share a private GitHub Repository with someone without adding them as a collaborator?
So, the main problem is I want to share the GitHub Repository with a recruiter. They have given me some task, which I completed and pushed it on GitHub. I can keep the repository Public and share it obviously, or keep it Private and send an Invite link to the recruiter, or add them as a collaborator.
However, I do not have the Email or GitHub account of the recruiter or HR. The main reason I wish not to keep my repository public is that other people from my University might try to copy my code if I keep the repository public.
You can say I am looking for something like, a YouTube video has an option to be kept unlisted, and only those people have access to it who have the unlisted link given to them by the owner.
I browsed certain articles regarding the same, but most of them were only regarding adding collaborators to the private repository.

Not currently. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22040
